# Postgresql join on array and transform to json

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to make a join on array containing ids and transform the result of this subselect into json (json array).

I have the following model:

￼[image]
The lnam_refs column contains identifiers that are related to the lnam column

I would like transform the column lnam_refs into something like [row_to_json(), row_to_json()] or [] or [row_to_json()] or …

I tried several methods but I can not achieve a clean result…

---

To try to be clearer :

```
Table in input: 
   id   |        label         |   lnam   |       lnam_refs 
--------+----------------------+----------+-----------------------
    1   |      'master1'       | 11111111 | {33333333}
    2   |      'master2'       | 22222222 | {44444444,55555555}
    3   |      'slave1'        | 33333333 | {}
    4   |      'slave2'        | 44444444 | {}
    5   |      'slave3'        | 55555555 | {}
    6   |      'master3'       | 66666666 | {}

Results Expected:
   id   |        label         |   lnam   |       lnam_refs       |             slaves
--------+----------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------  
    1   |      'master1'       | 11111111 | {33333333}            | [ {id: 3, label: 'slave1', lnam: 33333333, lnam_refs: []} ]
    2   |      'master2'       | 22222222 | {44444444,55555555}   | [ {id: 4, label: 'slave2', lnam: 44444444, lnam_refs: []}, {id: 5, label: 'slave3', lnam: 55555555, lnam_refs: []} ]
    6   |      'master3'       | 66666666 | {}                    | []
```

---

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You *really* need to make your desired result clearer. Give an example of what the resulting data would look like based on some initial data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @eurotrash : I updated my post hoping that it is more understandable ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. (I created a table called `t` with that data you supplied.)

```
SELECT *, (SELECT JSON_AGG(ROW_TO_JSON(t2)) FROM t t2 WHERE label LIKE 'slave%' AND lnam = ANY(t1.lnam_refs)) AS slaves
FROM t t1
WHERE label LIKE 'master%'
```

I use the `label` field in the `WHERE` clause as I don't know how else you're determining which records should be master etc.

Result:

```
1;master1;11111111;{33333333};[{"id":3,"label":"slave1","lnam":33333333,"lnam_refs":[]}]
2;master2;22222222;{44444444,55555555};[{"id":4,"label":"slave2","lnam":44444444,"lnam_refs":[]}, {"id":5,"label":"slave3","lnam":55555555,"lnam_refs":[]}]
6;master3;66666666;{};
```